# Burninate the "data" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

- [data](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) — 41 tagged, 21 this year

  > *no tag wiki/excerpt*

This extremely broad tag seems to be on a variety of questions where existing, more specific tags serve a much better, specific purpose.

In most cases, the tag seems to be referring to [cellular-data](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-data), but the tag also seems be used for [data-transfer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-transfer) or [data-synchronization](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-synchronization), as well as [data-recovery](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery) and the (more general but still more specific) [metadata](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metadata).

Should it be burninated?

Answer (score 3):

The questions in case also have [data-recovery](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery) or [recovery](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery) tagged.
It's  used in these questions as **reference to files** aka [data-transfer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-transfer) or [data-recovery](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery).

The best option would be to remove this tag as there are more detailed replacements for them already.